# Importing all files from a existing document library to a project web sever in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-studio-2013

Presently working on SP2013,I am having a site which is hosted on a server on a specified port, now I have created a project web application, can I import all the file from that normal site collection to newly created project web application in a single click.

Can anyone suggest me how to import all the document libraries and list library in a single click and export those files to the project web application.

Thanks in Advance

Any Suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since its 2 separate web applications. If you want to use no code. I suggest you go with Sharegate.
Sharegate will provide you a 30 day free trail. I think 30 days should be fine to achieve your task

Comment: Thank u dsouzajoel22, U r suggestion is very much helpful for me... Thanks a lot...

Comment: if you think this is the best solution for you. you can mark it as a correct ans by clicking on the tick mark below the down arrow